# How to send an automatic reply using webform?

Tags: forms, webforms

I'd like to send an automatic reply to every user who fills the form 
"Thank you for registration"+ link to a restricted webpage on my website -available only to registered users who filled that form.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that in the following way:

- Add an email field in webform. Set that field to get the users email by clicking "User email as default" option in the field's edit page.
- Configure your forms to send emails by going at node/%nid/webform/emails and choosing "Component value", then choose your component.
- After you add this "rule" you can then configure the actual email send to the user.

PS if you are not sure what the capabilities of a module are you can try it out at https://simplytest.me/.

Answer (score 0):

[Webform Reply To](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_reply_to)

> A key part of the Webform module is sending e-mails. Webform lets you
>   customize the name and e-mail address that is used for outgoing
>   e-mails, but often this is not enough. You cannot use Webform to set a
>   custom "Reply-To" e-mail header, for instance.